# Filter based on value of nested array of objects in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, filter

My json data is of below structure:

```
[
{"domain":"d1",
"technology":"Java",
"artifacts[{ 
  "artifactName":"app1",
  "hasVersionDiff":true,
  "environment":["DEV","SQA"],
  "version":["Not Available","1.0-R1"]
}]},

{"domain":"d2",
"technology":".net",
"artifacts[{ 
  "artifactName":"app4",
  "hasVersionDiff":false,
  "environment":["DEV","SQA"],
  "version":["1.0-R1","1.0-R1"]}]
}]
```

This result is compareResults variable. Now I am trying to filter this based on artifacts data (hasVersionDiff flag true) of each record. I am trying to filter using below:

```
this.compareResults.map(function(ComparisonResult) {
        ComparisonResult.artifacts = ComparisonResult.artifacts.filter(x => x.hasVersionDiff == true)
    });
```

But it is not filtering, can someone explain why this is not working?

Comment: Can you share the expected output from your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because with `map`, you need to `return` the new item. (I also fixed your object structure to make it valid):

```js
const compareResults = [{
    "domain": "d1",
    "technology": "Java",
    "artifacts": [{
      "artifactName": "app1",
      "hasVersionDiff": true,
      "environment": ["DEV", "SQA"],
      "version": ["Not Available", "1.0-R1"]
    }]
  },

  {
    "domain": "d2",
    "technology": ".net",
    "artifacts": [{
      "artifactName": "app4",
      "hasVersionDiff": false,
      "environment": ["DEV", "SQA"],
      "version": ["1.0-R1", "1.0-R1"]
    }]
  }
];

const modified = compareResults.map(function(ComparisonResult) {
  ComparisonResult.artifacts = ComparisonResult.artifacts.filter(x => x.hasVersionDiff);
  return ComparisonResult;
});

console.log(modified);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

If you want to remove the entire object if `artifacts` is empty:

```js
const compareResults = [{
    "domain": "d1",
    "technology": "Java",
    "artifacts": [{
      "artifactName": "app1",
      "hasVersionDiff": true,
      "environment": ["DEV", "SQA"],
      "version": ["Not Available", "1.0-R1"]
    }]
  },

  {
    "domain": "d2",
    "technology": ".net",
    "artifacts": [{
      "artifactName": "app4",
      "hasVersionDiff": false,
      "environment": ["DEV", "SQA"],
      "version": ["1.0-R1", "1.0-R1"]
    }]
  }
];

const modified = compareResults.map(function(ComparisonResult) {
  ComparisonResult.artifacts = ComparisonResult.artifacts.filter(x => x.hasVersionDiff);
  return ComparisonResult;
}).filter(({ artifacts }) => artifacts.length);

console.log(modified);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Thank you Jack! That worked perfectly, is there way to not return domain, technology if artifacts has no data inside it?

Comment: How's that @user2262292?

Comment: Yayyyyyyyyyyy! Thank you @Jack

Comment: Always glad to help @user2262292

Comment: one question, it looks like my original data is also changing when I do this, for 2nd record of compareResults, artifacts is showing no value, is there way to not modify original?

Comment: Solved my issue by using below to keep original data:
 this.originalResult= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.compareResults));

Answer (score 0):

I implemented recursive function with which nested array of objects can be filtered layer by layer from top to bottom. Explore, play and modify my script in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDXMDeOexAlnAFwwCMANEcbospdg2wfe22ZQMx1cuTBC06D2hcVLw8YADgHSpAMxJgEAGwD6GhAE8ApgCctIAEYArA8ChVKAImUgQ9sUtwBfN+IC63hh6K4pLuMLIArEFKwqKhDCFx3BTyUYl4qurauoYm5lY2AEwOZghGrmmeqaEJFbiyAJxVaRmaOvrGppbWULwOTiD95RVecX7SI+xjeIGcNaTJBU3wSCKY-sRzUrIALEtCK7EVm2kNe6EtWe25XTbbxaUlZetSE+5T4jPSx4KyAGxnbBia1q3zisioAAYAUoLm0cp18lBwn1nI8hmlPkdnu5wbRsTC1K1sh08t1fvcjIN8eNqXh3oJXgx6V4-Fg2aBILAjAY4ABXYDGNAwAAUCGAwEoAEEjEZ9AAeBBgPQAPhoYUoir0AEo0MqYGLgAA6DnAJDCkiG4RagDc7PA0Bgqg0UA6YAM0B5Wm5wF5RggJAAbgYhcKnS6TGQIFKZfLNaqYBoDEGNJQwLyALZmYxqoHS2V6BVK5U66P5wsq3UcYgch2J5NaSOl2NFoVhjqRjB1gwaek12BugAeUB0Se7Qq7GhgAGpqJw+zAIN3ujymwW40LhIa20ZhcLgAALEgaOAI7oapU61B60F4blQX1gBOj7SRw0QEDpgzmuCVshoVDoAeR4nqSNiGmQOoMJwHhanO9r9gYQ5aLmMZri26CLomNg8oa3J8gKwp4fy2aYD4sGkMoIoTv+6Dbg2cAQIaiZgAA5lA+4wAAtFQWrfHeD4Lku2E-tBnD8UYj50W6Hont6vr+kGoZHuG9EQKgdGRmqE6oIOw4TjmKw6Yhw5WlgXhYDWICJkxIAsUpzquu6LqydY8mBl+GAYAUPhqhgvw+ZgjTUFQPgBVCyzIFqWpAA)